# Selenium Creating unique username each and every time when I run the script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating new user, each and every time I have to create new username. Using below code i can't generate unique username each time when I run the script. Please help me out

```
int i = 0;

for(int count1=0; count1 <10000; i++){
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("classroomuser"+i);
i++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using counter, use time in milliseconds from epoch, which will create unique user every time.

```
Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("classroomuser" + d);
```

For more details, go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Comment: Thanks TDHM and Vinay. The above code is working fine. I got user like "classroomuserThu May 08 15:57:03 IST 2014.". But, My application don't accept ':'. Is there any other alternative to avoid colon?

Answer (score 0):

If java then you can also use the class RandomUtils. This has the method to create random strings. The more number of letters the lesser the chance of repetition if we take permutations into account. Happy coding.